# Is it possible for the firmware of an SSD be infected by malware/malicious rootkits via the internet?

Tags: internet, rootkits, spyware, firmware, ssd

I am asking this because based on Snowden's relevations, bad actors "interdict" (intercept) shipments of routers, HDDs, SSDs, servers, etc., install malicious rootkits and spyware in the firmware and then send the infected hardware to their intended targets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible, as long as the firmware on your device is updatable. That depends on the vendor, but most do have updatable firmware. If the bad actor had enough resources he could reverse engineer the update utility and firmware itself to insert anything they wanted there, as long as it was small enough to fit on the tiny flash memory in the SSD/HDD.

If you're interested in hardware hacks, there has been one that (supposedly) compromised the supply chain of Supermicro motherboards recently: [here](https://www.bloomberg.com/news/features/2018-10-04/the-big-hack-how-china-used-a-tiny-chip-to-infiltrate-america-s-top-companies)

Comment: Thanks for your reply and the reference to write-up by Bloomberg. It's very strange that up till now, nobody has produced physical evidence of the tiny chip. All that we have read in the media so far is based on "he says, they say, we say".

Comment: "_If you're interested in hardware hacks, there has been one that compromised the supply chain of Supermicro motherboards recently_"  That's not entirely accurate.  There have been _unfounded claims_ from Bloomberg which say that.  There's plenty of reason to be skeptical, for example: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/195741/a-hardware-spy-chip-was-found-in-server-equipment-recently-how-does-it-work/

Comment: OP is asking about attacks over the _internet_. Hard drive firmware cannot be updated directly over the internet, only locally via ATA commands.

Comment: @forest if you get a piece of malware on your computer it will have local access to the drive to update the firmware, that's how I understood the question. Also technically you could just inject the update code and package to any suitable vulnerability

Comment: @JMac I've now included the uncertainty of this hack! Thanks for pointing this out :)

Comment: @Genesis You may want to specify that, since I doubt OP was thinking of that, otherwise every question related to malware could contain "over the internet". He may have been thinking of OTA updates like some BIOSes have, and HDD firmware most certainly does not have OTA updates.